# Erro 1042 ao instalar Mysql 8.011 no win 10

Tags: mysql, windows

[image: Log de registros da instalação]

Esse erro aparece na parte Starting Server.

Comment: Esta instalando com perfil administrador?

Comment: O Windows Firewall está ligado?

Comment: @PauloH.Hartmann a opção de " Executar como adm" não aparece.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura, tentei instalar com o Firewall desligado e também não deu certo :/

Comment: Tente fazer, para máquina onde está instalando, um telnet para a porta 3306. Se for fazer telnet da mesma máquina, abra um prompt de comando e digite `telnet localhost 3306`, e me diga o que acontece

Comment: telnet não é reconhecido como um comando externo ou interno